# get the python-related system/installation information from linux command line

Tags: linux, filesystems, python, environment-variables, path

Given an existing Python development environemnt, which command line can let me get those information such as

```
Python path
Environment variables
```

For instance, I am trying to use the following command line to create Python virtual environment,

```
virtualenv x --system-site-packages
```

Therefore, I need to figure out where are those system-site-packages installed on the system. Which command-line can enable me to get the path name of --system-site-packages for a given system?

Comment: `--system-site-packages` is a boolean flag, so it should link to the system packages automatically. Or is there something else you want do with the information?

Comment: Hi Raphael, how to print the information linked by --system-site-packages?